# How can I change the lemma in a paragraphed footnote into bold in eledmac?

Tags: eledmac

Does anyone know how to change the format of the lemma in a paragraphed footnote in `eledmac`. I would like to have them bold.

Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, BCOR 20mm, twoside, 11pt, titlepage]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{eledmac, eledpar}
\footparagraph{A}

\newcommand{\myedtext}[2]{\edtext{#1}{\lemma{\textbf{#1}}{\Afootnote{#2}}}}

\Xnotenumfont{\bfseries}

\begin{document}
    \beginnumbering
        \pstart

            pergant ut hostis terga euntis caedere,\\
            quem gaza diues ac triumphus nobilis\\
            captis \myedtext{tenebant}{\Afootnote{tenebat \textit{S p. c.}}} inpeditum copiis.\\ %25


        \pend
    \endnumbering
\end{document}
```

Comment: Printing the lemmata properly is tricky; a simple workaround is: `\newcommand{\myedtext}[2]{\edtext{#1}{\lemma{\textbf{#1}}{\Afootnote{#2}}}}`, assuming `\footparagraph{A}`.  If that's no good, please edit the question to provide a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)).

Comment: Note that in your updated example, you are now calling `\Afootnote` twice, which will fail.  The macro I suggested has a 'built-in' call to `\Afootnote`, so you would just write: `\myedtext{tenebant}{tenebat \textit{S p. c.}}`.  (Which I would rewrite as `\myedtext{tenebant}{tenebat \emph{S p.\ c.}}`, mainly to correct the spacing after the `p.`.

Comment: the suggestion by jon is the best. An other solution will be that I add an option to eledmac to allow customize font for lemma. But that implies to think about the consequencies for the lemma font selection : by default, the font of a lemma in a notes is the same as in the main text...

Answer (score 3):

One year later, some one ask me for a more general solution. So the version 2.7.0 of reledmac (successor of eledmac),send on CTAN on 2015/11/28, provides a new hook : `\Xlemmafont[<series>]{<Tex font command>}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertineotf}
\usepackage[noeledsec,nofamiliar,series={A,B,C,D}]{reledmac}
\begin{document}
\Xlemmadisablefontselection{}
\Xarrangement[A]{normal}
\Xarrangement[B]{twocol}
\Xarrangement[C]{threecol}
\Xarrangement[D]{paragraph}
\Xlemmafont{\bfseries}
\Xendlemmafont{\bfseries}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\edtext{toto}{\Afootnote{sncf}\Bfootnote{ratp}\Cfootnote{metropolitain}\Dfootnote{sur le coup de dix heures}\Aendnote{titi}}
\pend
\endnumbering
\vskip 1cm
\doendnotes{A}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your dedication to critical edition typesetting is much appreciated!!