# eledmac: formatting endnotes

Tags: formatting, endnotes, eledmac

I try to format endnotes with `eledmac` in a way that I can use them to correct printing errors of the original text, but unfortunately i don't understand how to change the fonts.

Say, for example, I edit this text:

```
I did it \edtext{my}{\Aendnote{may}} way
```

In the Appendix I want to have this:

> p. 7, 2 **my**] my

But I don't get the manual on how to format "my" in bold and get the bracket. Can anyone help?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: actually, the lemma has the same formating than the main text. There are no option for a ≠ formating. But as you are not the only one which asked for it (cf https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202134/how-can-i-change-the-lemma-in-a-paragraphed-footnote-into-bold-in-eledmac) you could ask for a new feature on https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues.

Comment: but the solution of jon is semanticly better.

Answer (score 1):

The commands involved behind the scenes for the creating and printing of lemmata are very involved.  Unless the package is extended to provide this option, you need to cheat using the `\lemma` command.  (OK, you don't need to cheat in this way, but this is the simplest way to achieve what you want....)

Here's one way, using a simple `\if` switch.  It also relies on using an abstracted version of the `\edtext` command, which I strongly recommend for legibility reasons.  The input file of critical edition texts gets really difficult to read (and debut) even if avoid error-prone coding like using:

```
\edtext{<correct text>}{\Aendnote{<incorrect text>}}
```

Slightly cleaner is a definition like:

```
\newcommand{\variant}[2]{\edtext{#1}{\Aendnote{#2}}}
```

which is then used in the file as

```
\variant{correct}{incorrect}
```

(Apologies if you already are doing something like that but are simply trying to keep your example low-level for the sake of the question.)

Anyway, try the below file. If you comment out the `\prooftrue` line, your lemmata will be set regularly, if you uncomment it, the lemmata will be bold.

```
% Set up an "ifproof" switch
\newif\ifproof
% When you want the bold lemma in the notes, uncomment the following
% line:
%\prooftrue
%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{eledmac}

\ifproof
  \newcommand{\variant}[2]{%
    \edtext{#1}{\lemma{\textbf{#1}}\Aendnote{#2}}}
\else
  \newcommand{\variant}[2]{%
    \edtext{#1}{\Aendnote{#2}}}
\fi

\begin{document}
 \beginnumbering
 \pstart

 I did it \variant{my}{may} way.

 \pend
 \endnumbering

\section{A Endnotes}
\doendnotes{A}

\end{document}
```